# AutoComplete Controller Action not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have a editbox which is linked to auto-complete handler, when I type any character the controller method itself not calling and its not even working also.

**jQuery**

```
$("#NameInput").autocomplete({
    minChars: 3,
    delay: 100,
    cacheLength: 25,
    autoFill: true,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Data/GetNames", dataType: "json",
            data: { id: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.label, value: item.id }; //updated code
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the controller method.

**C#**

```
[RequiresRole(Roles = "su, da, rv, sp, dg, ap, ua")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public string GetNames(string term )
{
    //perform DB operations
    return String.Empty;
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<input type="text" name="NameInput" id="NameInput" class="NameInputField" maxlength="80" tabindex="3" />
```

Here `getNames` method itself not calling, at the time of launching I'm just registering for auto-complete handler. What will be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the issue lies in your ajax call. In the data in you pass, you assign `request.term` to `id` - yet your controller method is looking for a parameter called `term`.

Change your ajax from

```
data: { id: request.term }
```

to

```
data: { term: request.term }
```

---

Alternatively, change your controller method from

```
public string GetNames(string term)
```

to

```
public string GetNames(string id)
```

Comment: Hi, i m confused, If i make data: { term: request.term } and if i receive as id, then where is the reference id is present in the block? i.e data: { term: request.term } in this no id identifier is found. will it work?

Comment: It didnt work, do we need to call autocomplete every time when the text changes in editbox?. or once u register its enough??

Comment: The jQuery will do the management for you. You just need to do one or the other of the two suggested methods.

Comment: Hi, i tried like above code, still no luck, anything wrong in my code?. why its failing?

Answer (score 0):

i think your trouble in url "/Data/GetNames", you should change it to "**/Data.aspx/GetNames**" and

```
[RequiresRole(Roles = "su, da, rv, sp, dg, ap, ua")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string GetNames(string term )
{
  //perform DB operations
  return String.Empty;
}
```

Also it is good article [Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Comment: No, that need not be, i have tried without that also for clickevent and all its working fine

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what plugin you use, i was using the plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/.

So, i found out the solution for that, here are demo examples http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/